# How to write to GeoFire from Python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

The GeoFire SDK only supports Java, Obj-C and JS. Let's say I want to save an item with its location data in python, how will the data structure look like.
So far I have 

`item['location'] = [float(lat), float(long)]`

It doesn't seem to work when I try to use GeoFire.js on the client side to fetch data.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like GeoFire is essentially client logic (Java, Obj-C and JS) using [geohashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) backed by FireBase's Realtime Database (see "but really how" in their [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/09/geofire-location-queries-for-fun-and.html)). Since there's no python client, it's not possible out of the box. You'd either need to find a python wrapper for their supported libraries, or do something using geohashing and Realtime Database directly.